# Can I use fullpage.js functions parallel?

Tags: fullpage.js

I would like to customize the awesome fullpage.js plugin to my website. It is not clear for me, however, if it is possible to use onLeave and afterLoad functions parallel or not. Thank you!

Comment: You've been answered [in the GitHub issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2230). They are not parallel as stated in the docs. Which means they are not being fired at the same time. But of course you can use them both in the initialization.

Comment: Thank you! It is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, **yes** you can use both `onLeave` and `afterLoad` callbacks within the same initialization. In fact, you can use **all** options and callbacks necessary to fulfill your app needs.

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization) if you need more information or examples on more complex initializations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use the following code but it does not work. Am I wrong anything?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                //do something
        }
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
                //do something
        }
});